# Array to input 100 numbers

Tags: java, arrays, input, min

I need to allow the user to type exactly 100 numbers, so 100 inputs, and then print the minimum number out of those. It'd be very inefficient to type 100 .nextInt() lines and I thought that I could use an array of exactly 100 inputs and then once it's done find the min and print it out. But I do not know how to do it, so what is a simple way to do that? Thanks

Comment: for loop, any loop with counter....

Comment: @Antoniossss , I have never used those or know what that is, that is why I am asking for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without an array lets see how.

```
int smallest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;//assume smallest to be largest integer
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    int num=sc.nextInt();//this will run 100 times and hence will input 100 number
    if(num<smallest){//if number is smaller than smallest then num is smallest
       smallest=num; 
    }
}
System.out.println(smallest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code sample.
I ran it on my computer and it works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] Numbers = new int[100];
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    for (int x=0;x<100;x++){
        System.out.println("Enter Number");
        Numbers[x]= input.nextInt();
    }

    int min = Numbers[0];

    for (int x=1;x<100;x++){
      if (Numbers[x] < min){
        min = Numbers[x];
      }
    }

    System.out.println("The Min number is :"+min);
  }
}
```

Hope this Helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need array, this example is using recursive function/method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = prompt(sc, 1, 5); /* prompts for 5 values, change as required */
        sc.close();
        System.out.printf("Minium value is: %d%n", min);
    }

    private static int prompt(Scanner sc, int count, int times){
        System.out.printf("Enter number %d of %d: ", count, times);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if(count == times){
            return n;
        }
        return Math.min(n, prompt(sc, (1 + count), times));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for asking this can be done without any array as explained in other answers but if you want to use a array declare it as

```
int arr[]=new int[100];
```

enter the values in it using a for loop,
then apply

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

arr[0] will be the minimum value element.

Comment: and see www.javatpoint.com for any basic java references it is a very good site to learn basic java